# How can I do with the Date Picker in Graphical Style?

Tags: swift, macos, datepicker

I create a button with a popover date picker. Inside the date picker, I control dragged an IBAction to receive the date I pick and print out. However, whenever I select another date, it will always print out twice. (Select the same day will print out once)

I would like to get ONE value from date picker whenever I select. How can I fix it?

[here is what I've done.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7xf5.png)

Comment: Please add a print statement in the IBAction method to check if that is getting called twice. If yes, then right click on the buttons in the date picker and see that they are connected to the IBAction only once.

Comment: I just print(sender.dateValue) inside the IBAction. It still prints out twice .. I wonder if it has something to do with mouseUp and mouseDown event ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this in awakeFromNib or viewDidLoad :

```
    let theAction = Int(NSEventMask.MouseExitedMask.rawValue)
    theDatePicker.sendActionOn(theAction)
```